# Correct Way for 'article' structured data in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7, structured-data

My question is not restricted to drupal CMS. 
I am working on SEO amelioration by adding structured data on every "article" of my website.
I dont understand why "Google structured data testing tool" cannot valid this kind of ldjson object ...
Somebody can help me ?

Thanks in advance

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{ 
   "@context":"http://schema.org/",
   "@type":"Article",
   "articleBody":"azea",
   "speakable":{ 
      "@type":"SpeakableSpecification",
      "cssSelector":[ 
         "p"
      ]
   },
   "accessMode":[ 
      "textual",
      "visual"
   ],
   "accessModeSufficient":[ 
      "textual",
      "visual"
   ],
   "accessibilityControl":[ 
      "fullKeyboardControl",
      "fullMouseControl"
   ],
   "backstory":"Test Workflow 01",
   "dateCreated":"2019-10-08",
   "dateModified":"2019-10-15",
   "headline":"Test Workflow 01 Redacteur AABis",
   "inLanguage":{ 
      "@type":"Language",
      "name":"French",
      "alternateName":"fr"
   },
   "isAccessibleForFree":true,
   "isFamilyFriendly":true,
   "producer":{ 
      "@type":"Organization",
      "name":"TEST"
   },
   "author":{ 
      "@type":"Organization",
      "name":"TEST"
   },
   "provider":{ 
      "@type":"Organization",
      "name":"TEST"
   },
   "publisher":{ 
      "@type":"Organization",
      "name":"TEST",
      "logo":"https://test.fr/sites/default/files/logo.png"
   },
   "mainEntityOfPage":"/node/xxx",
   "sourceOrganization":{ 
      "@type":"Organization",
      "name":"TEST"
   },
   "text":"azea",
   "articleSection":"TEST",
   "keywords":"Test Workflow 01",
   "datePublished":"2019-10-08",
   "thumbnailUrl":"https://test.fr/sites/default/files/drupal/201906/image/logo_connect_3.png",
   "image":"https://test.fr/sites/default/files/drupal/201906/image/logo_connect_3.png"
}</script>
```

**More ...** 
I dont using a drupal module for that, only custom code on custom module.
The specific error is on 'publisher object', see the image below . 
Thanks you again !

[data structured error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcIiU.png)

Comment: Which error do you get? Please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Are you using [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/schema_metatag) for drupal to use JSON LD structures ? This is the first step I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, i edited my post with more informations. I had posted all the data in order to test directly on https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/